# How can I build a constructor-like function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I read the CHAPTER 6 OBJECT-ORIENTED PROGRAMMING of Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, It shows a pattern for create object by constructor.

```
// implicit way
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var person1 = new Person('Greg')
person1 instanceof Person
```

> To create a new instance of Person, use the new operator. Calling a constructor in this manner essentially causes the following four steps to be taken:
>
> 1. Create a new object.
> 2. Assign the this value of the constructor to the new object (so this points to the new object).
> 3. Execute the code inside the constructor (adds properties to the new object).
> 4. Return the new object.

That show the implicit way how an object instance be created.

And I want to follow it explicitly. Something like:

```
function Person(name) {
  var o = Object.call(this)  // step 1 and step 2
  o.name = name              // step 3
  return o                   // step 4
}

var person1 = new Person('Greg')
person1 instanceof Person // false
```

In fact, It can't work as the constructor pattern. Why? And how can I modify my code to create a constructor with the explicit way?

https://javascript.info/constructor-new

Comment: Jonas Wilms has the answer, but note that if you implement a constructor like that it doesn’t really act like a proper constructor and you won’t be able to inherit from it with `class extends`, for example. It’s just a regular function. (Bit misleading to continue using `new` with it, in the same vein.)

Comment: `Object.call(this)` doesn't do what you think it does - the `Object` function ignores its context. What exactly did you intend this to do?

Comment: You are still calling the second `Person` function with `new`, so what is the point of doing the stuff twice? This will hardly result in what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Object.call(this)` makes little sense, as that function does not care of its context and returns a plain object. Instead you can use:

```
  Object.create(this.constructor.prototype)
```

Comment: Thank you. You save my time!  And I use `the Object.create(this) `  also have the same result. And it seems this way is follow what the book description. And can you show me some article about `new constructor prototype __proto__`, I can't figout out concept about that :)

Comment: If you do `Object.create(this)` the prototype chain is `o -> this -> Person.prototype -> Object.prototype` ... The way I suggested creates `o -> Person.prototype -> Object.prototype` so there isn't an unused object in the chain.

Comment: Your experience is really rich. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The book quoted leaves out a seriously important detail of what `new` does:

> 1 Create a new object.

really means

1.1 Create a new object,

1.2 which has been prototyped on the constructor function's `prototype` property.

Hence the results of:

```js
function Person(name) {
  var o = Object.create( Person.prototype);
  
  o.name = name              // step 3
  return o                   // step 4
}

var person1 = new Person('Greg')
console.log( person1 instanceof Person); // true
console.log( person1.constructor)         // Person
```

Not that you would do this in real code, but for  learning purposes it's an interesting demonstration.

**The  constructor property**

Generally an object inherits its "constructor" property from its inheritance chain, searching backwards from the object's `__proto` property.

You could create a local own-property of an object called "constructor" which would then shadow the inherited value (and which would also be enumerable by default).

If you set the constructor property of a function's prototype property, its value changes without the property becoming enumerable in the process:

```js
function F() {}
console.log (F.prototype.hasOwnProperty("constructor")); // true
let f = new F();
console.log( f.constructor.name);  // F
F.prototype.constructor = Object;
let g = new F();
console.log( g.constructor.name);  // Object
F.prototype.foo = "bar";
for( var prop in F.prototype) {
   console.log( "F.prototype.%s = %s", prop, F.prototype[ prop]); // foo only
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's my purpose to figure out what the constructor is. Cause I can use it, but I don't know what happen behind. I will read it carefully:)

Comment: Eriice, My apologies - the `constructor` property of a functions prototype property is created at the same time the function object is created by `Function`, not `new`. @JonasWilms thank you, I' ve removed I.3.

Comment: OMG, don't apology. From your answer I learn a lot. But It's a pity that you two delete the comments. I think it's also helpful for us. I haven't had time to study them yet.